# "Oops! Something Bad Happened!" on daily basis

Tags: bug, error-message

I get this at least once a day. It said I could provide more information here, so I'll do that. I was saving an edit to my question; the page URL was https://stackoverflow.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/posts/14200441/edit-submit/53b23380-ce62-41cd-8eec-3ae5624b4c95

It's frustrating, as it causes my edit to be completely lost.

[EDIT] It happened just now on this question as well...
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/posts/161857/edit-submit/38004d1e-f672-4ef1-979a-4ef1dd0b12c4
[EDIT 2] Happened again on this question.
[EDIT 3] Again.

I am using IE8.
[EDIT 4] Same error while adding this line above; strange, meta seems to have this error a lot more (edit: maybe not, could just be a fluke that meta is more common)

Cannot figure out how to reproduce at will, but will edit actual error here when I see it (found in HTML source).

According to the HTML source, the error I'm getting: *XSRF validation: Request did not have required form value 'fkey'*

I am not running in compatibility mode.

Comment: [meta-tag:status-norepro]

Comment: Usually pressing on the back button gets back your edit (unless it was inline)

Comment: I use Back often, but 90% of the time it brings me to my unedited question. I use IE.

Comment: @jbu - version number?

Comment: @Lix Edited into question.

Comment: It may be an IE8-specific probably. That browser is no longer officially supported. When you get the error, try inspecting the source and look for a HTML comment like `<!-- Actual error: xxxxx -->` just below the error message, it should have further details.

Comment: @animuson I see. WinXP is run here w/ 2000+ PCs, so I don't think we can use IE9. Will look at source.

Comment: The 'something bad' that happened was the fact that you're using IE.